# Trying to get the element in xslt 1.0.But unable to get in response xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xalan

[Reqeust xml is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A7pH.jpg)

```
<xsl:if test="../tn:notification/evt0:relationship/evt0:businessInteractionIdentifier/evt0:customerOrderIdentifier/evt0:id/evt0:idContext/evt0:value">
        <tns:projectIdentifier>

                        <tns:idContext>
                                                            <tns:value>
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="../tn:notification/evt0:relationship/evt0:businessInteractionIdentifier/evt0:customerOrderIdentifier/evt0:id/evt0:idContext/evt0:value" />
                                </tns:value>
                                </tns:idContext>
                                                    [Response xsd attached][2]

                </tns:projectIdentifier>
```

This is the xsl code that is written but not working

Comment: Please post your XML, not an image. Please also post a working XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Code I think your problem solve

```
<xsl:if test="../tn:notification/evt0:relationship/evt0:businessInteractionIdentifier/evt0:customerOrderIdentifier/evt0:idContext/evt0:value">
<tns:projectIdentifier>
<tns:idContext>
<tns:value>
<xsl:value-of select="//evt0:value" />
</tns:value>
</tns:idContext>
</tns:projectIdentifier>
```

Comment: what you want output

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
<xsl:if test="../../tn:notification/evt0:relationship/evt0:businessInteractionIdentifier/evt0:customerOrderIdentifier/evt0:idContext/evt0:value">
```

I kept everything else unchanged.

Comment: <xsl:if test="../../tn:notification/evt0:relationship/evt0:businessInteractionIdentifier/evt0:customerOrderIdentifier/evt0:idContext/evt0:value">